# Html line(horizontal rule) is not supporting in Android Gmail client

Tags: android, html, gmail

[image]

This is a sample image of compose message box of Android Gmail client , here I have to insert a line (Html line with the help of Hr tag or table) at position (Red mark between that two statements) with the **custom html message** , I try a lot with different ways but I am not getting any line.

Please share your idea on this problem .
Any suggestion over Html support in Android Gmail client will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hr {
height: 1px;
border: 0;
background: #line_color;
display: block;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this is working fine with android default web view but it is not working with android gmail client.

Comment: try to increase the height to 2px, else try this: 
hr {height: 0;border: 0;border-top: 2px solid #line_color;display: block}

Comment: last suggestion: try width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

Could just consider using a border? I find `hr` is often too much effort if the effect you are looking for can be achieved with borders.